# Excel Activex Textbox operating differently on two computers

Tags: excel, textbox, activex

Both machines are Windows 10, Office 365. One is a Surface (S) the other a Dell (D).

On Machine S, key entry into a textbox works as expected (updates as characters are keyed). On Machine D, textbox is not updated until focus is moved.

Comment: On yet another machine, key entry into a (the same in all cases) textbox works as expected. That machine is running Excel 2016. Machine D is running Office 365 but Excel 2008. (Why a minus 1 vote?)

Answer (score 0):

Machine D has two monitors. The issue occurs when the sheet is on the second monitor. Found it during a Quick Assist. Did not pursue it further with Microsoft, since the solution is likely to be outside of Excel (Microsoft 365/ Excel build 13127.20408); and a workaround is to not use a second monitor for this workbook.